# Java Opensource E-Commerce solution

Tags: java, open-source, e-commerce

I believe there are a lot of similar questions even on stackoverflow. But most of them are dated 1-2 years ago. Sorry about same question again.

Could you suggest easy to run and tweak java based opensource E-Commerce solution. Before i used Magento, but it was really hard to change code at start. I spend almost 2 week to realize how Magento works. Performance was not good enough too.

Now i'm looking for simple java solution, which can be customized or rewritten easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on the hunt for more or less the same.

Up until now, KonaKart has been my prime candidate. But their entire stack isn't opensource, this is limited to (snippet from http://www.konakart.com/product/customization):

> The parts of KonaKart that customers are most likely to want to customize are all open >source. These include the Struts action classes and forms, the JSPs, the velocity templates, >the BIRT reports, the payment modules, order total modules, shipping modules and the GWT One >Page Checkout code. They are shipped under the GNU Lesser General Public License

An alternative is http://www.shopizer.com/ which offer the entire codebase under the LGPL license.

Since I'm purely in the very early stages of spotting a suitable system, I can't say much about performance of either system.